# HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure for a web project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I'm getting the error message mentioned above when trying to run any web project. I've tried an empty website, a webforms project, and an MVC project, and all of them give me that error. This is in a solution with a Web API project (neither of these are .NET core, but rather the original .NET framework). If I start an entirely new solution and just create an empty website, that works fine. Can't seem to find a reason that makes sense for my circumstances.

Comment: Like [this GitHub thread discussed](https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/issues/406), the actual **502.5 error page** indicates what's up, which you clearly did not want to share. So this question cannot be answered at all.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the "applicationhost.config" file under the ".vs" directory in the solution folder must have somehow been bad. Once I deleted that and then created a new project, it worked fine.